# Snowflake Count Group By With Condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to measure the ratio of "Total Query Fails per Object / Total Query Count per Object"

My data looks like the below.

| query_id | object | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | success |
| 2 | a | fail |
| 3 | a | fail |
| 4 | b | success |
| 5 | b | fail |

I'm able to use the below to measure total fails per object / total fails e.g.

```
select
object
count(distinct query_id) as num_distinct_queries
ratio_to_report(count(distinct query_id) over () as percent_of_total_fails
from my_table
where status='fail'
group by object
order by 3
```

| object | num_distinct_queries | percent_of_total_fails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 0.666666 |
| b | 1 | 0.333333 |

I want to achieve something like:

| object | num_distinct_queries | num_fails | percent_of_fails_per_table |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 2 | 0.666666 |
| b | 2 | 1 | 0.5 |

Any advice how to achieve the second option? Total fails per object / Total queries per object.

Answer (score 3):

Using [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html) to perform conditional aggregation:

```
select object,
  count(distinct query_id) as num_distinct_queries,
  count_if(status='fail') AS num_fails,
  count_if(status='fail')/count(*) as percent_of_total_fails
from my_table
group by object
order by 3;
```

Output:

[image]

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2db6fed321427b5477e4cd394eb15908)**